# hamburger icon doesn't close the nagation drawer

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, uinavigationcontroller

I'm using navigation component with navigation drawer with RTL layout support , the drawer open fine but when I click to icon again to close it nothing happen

[image]

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard)
    window.decorView.layoutDirection = View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL

    navController = Navigation.findNavController(this,R.id.navHost)

    appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph,drawerLayout)

    navigationView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController,appBarConfiguration)

}

override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    navController = Navigation.findNavController(this,R.id.navHost)
    return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
}
```

Comment: try this : 
 `if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }`
On hamburger click.

Answer (score 0):

After a long time I been found the solution, you have to create an ActionBarDrawerToggle object and sync it, after that you should override the method on onOptionsItemSeletected that's all.

```
private lateinit var toggle: ActionBarDrawerToggle

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?){

    toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.open, 
    R.string.close)

    toggle.syncState()
}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {

    if (toggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
        return true
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}
```

as a summary I didn't put the extra code for the configuration of the drawer.